# Free software physically modeled piano?

Tags: keyboard, midi, piano, midi-instrument

Is there any free code online for a physically modeled (i.e. not sample-based) piano sound?  Examples of commercial software include Pianoteq and the firmware for Roland's V-Piano.  This is for an open-source digital piano project I'm working on.

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser.com

Comment: Please don't use the "belongs=on-xxx" tags.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347250/tone-generation-in-cocoa-touch

Comment: Why does this belong on superuser if he's asking for source code?

Comment: Please keep us posted on your project! Where is it hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a definitive answer (I don't know anything about the topic), but here are a few links that might be useful:

- http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1289424
- http://lib.tkk.fi/Diss/2007/isbn9789512290666/
- http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/doc/nyquist/part15.html
- http://old.nabble.com/Generating-piano-sound-td20395650.html
- http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~sinclair/content/stk_piano
- http://old.nabble.com/Piano-patch-td17840932.html

Comment: Thanks!  I had seen most of the codeless citations in my own searches, but I'm very intrigued by the Nyquist link:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/doc/nyquist/part15.html

and the STK link:

http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~sinclair/content/stk_piano

Thanks!