# Play a beep in C, MacOS

Tags: c, macos, beep

How can my program play a beep? Also Is it possible to play a sound with frequency and duration?

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C file and command line tool that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows. For Mac check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347250/tone-generation-in-cocoa-touch).

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> // WinApi header 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
Beep(523,500); // 523 hertz (C5) for 500 milliseconds 
Beep(587,500); 
Beep(659,500); 
Beep(698,500); 
Beep(784,500); 

cin.get(); // wait 
return 0;     
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked, and the link isn't related either.

Answer (score 0):

There's `NSBeep()` in AppKit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  putchar('\a');
  return 0;
}
```