# Can I generate tones (music) on fly?

Tags: ios, cocoa, macos, generics, core-audio

Can I generate some tones on fly and play the sound? For example, if I want to generate DO RI MI FA SO LA XI tones and play them? 
  It seems the sound APIs are all for playing exists audio files.
Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `DO RE MI FA SO LA TI DO` refers to the notes of a major scale in music =)

Comment: I am not quite clear about the music notes. The "tone" should be a wave of samples? Pure sound wave is sine wave right? How I can make the "tone" sound like from a piano?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tone Generation in Cocoa Touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347250/tone-generation-in-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Matt Gallagher's [An iOS tone generator](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MIDI](http://www.midi.org/) API (e.g. [Java's](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html)). You'll need either a MIDI-capable sound card, an external synthesizer, or a software synthesizer (e.g. [timidity](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: +1 for MIDI, -1 for "you'll need a sound card [on your iPhone/iPad]". ;-)

Comment: OK, I did not see the 'ios' tag :-)